# Batch - How to find strings from the first file in the second file and print which strings from the first file don't exist in the second one?

Tags: string, batch-file, search, find

I have the first text file, example:

```
amet
sint
perspiciatis
minima
```

And I have the second file full of text, example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I want the output to be:

```
perspiciatis
minima
```

I tried using
`findstr /G:1.txt 2.txt >> C:\Temp\results.txt`
But this prints lines from the second file that contain the line from the first one, but I want the lines from the first file that don't exists in the second file.

Answer (score -1):

OFC I found the answer after I posted a question

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (1.txt) do (
    findstr %%A 2.txt > nul || echo %%A
)
pause
```

Comment: You might want to consider word boundaries: `findstr "\<%%A\>"` (see `findstr /?`). You don't want `Absinth` to be recognized as `sint`, do you? Also the `/i` switch could be helpul.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**